# how to ignore irelevent gps location updates in android?

Tags: android, geolocation, android-gps

I'm working on a app that uses `GPS` location data.

The problem is the condition that the app is working in. sometimes there is no **internet connection** and some times there is a **roof** or the user will go in the **tunnels** and in these conditions i will get some wrong points from `GPS`.

The point is how can I ignore the wrong points from `GPS`?
I had an idea of listing last `10` or `20` points and get the average of distance between them and if new point distance `<=` average, then remove the last point and add new one to list.

But there is a problem ! sometimes  **the new point is right and from there I have right points.**
So how could I decide to ignore the point or keep it in the list . or maybe there is another way that i don't know?

Answer (score 0):

You probably have a listener which constantly updates. Try using this:

```
locationManager.getLastKnownLocation(provider)
```

Where `provider = LocationManager.GPS_PROVIDER;`

And call this method when you want to fetch the new location

Comment: from document says :  ` Note that this location could be out-of-date, for example if the device was turned off and moved to another location.
If the provider is currently disabled, null is returned.` so in my case it is not reliable.

Comment: Yes you only get the location once so if the device is moved you will need to call getLastKnownLocation when you need the newest location again.

Comment: Either you fetch the location when you decide so with getLastKnownLocation or you do as you have where you the location keeps updating which can slow down your application performance

Comment: the worker using my app to fill the check-list of equipment and before the save the checklist form , they have to get the correct location of the equipment to send it later and that location need to be correct because it is shows that worker actually went there and filled the check-list. some times some where it dos not shows the correct location because of the environment. i need to know that it is a right location of the device or not. if not i will not let them save the check-list till getting the right location. and i don't think it will effect the performance , maybe battrey though